# I am having issues adding Python folder to my path

Tags: macos, python-2.7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to add the Python 2.7 bin folder to my path in order to run elastic beanstalk. **Here is some output from my Terminal:**

➜  ~ echo $PATH
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

➜  ~ ~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/eb --version

EB CLI 3.8.9 (Python 2.7.1)

➜  ~ eb --version
zsh: command not found: eb

**And here is my export statement in .zshrc:**

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? EB seems to be installed fine, and the path variable seems to point to it.

Comment: Feel free to answer, but I ended up uninstalling awsebcli and brew installing it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilde character wasn't being expanded within the double-quoted string. If you had tried to execute `"~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/eb" --version` in your second example it wouldn't have worked either.

You could have set your path using something like `export PATH="/Users/peter/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"`, or potentially `export PATH=~/"Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"` (notice the tilde is outside the double-quotes.) I'd prefer the former, however.